# How to return ActiveRecord WhereChain as a standard relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I have this scope that is performing a product search. The problem is it returns `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain` when I need just a standard relation array of the Product objects.

I don't think I can use the standard .where() to achieve what I'm trying to do here. This works, but, it returns the wherechain that I don't want.

```rb
scope :product_search, -> (query) {
    I18n.transliterate(query)
        .downcase
        .gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
        .gsub(/[^\w\s]/, '')
        .split(' ')
        .map{ |w| "%#{w}%" }
        .reduce(self) do |dataset, word|
        binding.pry
      dataset.where{ product_search_format(full_title).like word }
    end
  }
```

For reference, product_search_format is an index in the db:

```rb
      t.index "product_search_format((full_title)::text) gin_trgm_ops", name: "app_products_full_title_search_idx", using: :gin
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need something like this

```
scope :product_search, ->(query) do
  pattern =
    I18n.transliterate(query)
      .downcase
      .gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
      .gsub(/[^\w\s]/, '')
      .split
      .join("|")

  where('product_search_format(full_title) ~ :pattern', pattern: pattern)
end
```

BTW split without args could be used as tokenizer (split string to words)

`~` operator is match operator in PostgreSQL, instead of this you can use `LIKE` and `%`-matchers